# Using list comprehension to reduce a function that transforms list of lists in tuples of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

i want  to change this function using a list comprehension in order that it will have 1 or to lines. the function transfor a list containing list  in a tuple containing tupples inside

```
def lol(lista):
        novotuplo = ()
            for i in range(len(lista)):
                novotuplo += (tuple(lista[i]),)

            return novotuplo
```

Comment: try `novotuplo = tuple((x,) for x in lista)`

Comment: `novotuplo = (tuple(lst) for lst in lista)`

Comment: please provide input & expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
novotuplo = tuple(tuple(item) for item in lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
lista = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
print(tuple(tuple(i) for i in lista))
# ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
```

A more explicit explanation of the above list comprehension would be create a `tuple` of all elements in `lista` converted to `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in a functional form, this is one way. You do not need an index here because `lst in lista` iterates over the elements directly.

```
lista = [[1],[2],[3]]
def lol(lista):
    novotuplo = tuple(tuple(lst) for lst in lista)
    return novotuplo

print (lol(lista))
# ((1,), (2,), (3,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the items to the `tuple()` constructor:

```
tuple(map(tuple, lista))
```

Comment: thanks , it worked ! can u explain me what does the code do clearly ! i am a beginer and this is for a project , if the teacher asks me i have to explain

Comment: Glad to be of help. To convert one list to a tuple, you can use the `tuple()` constructor on the list. To convert a list of lists to a tuple of tuples, use the [`map` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply the `tuple` constructor on every item of the given list `lista`, and then convert the output of `map` (which is a generator) to a tuple with another call to the `tuple()` constructor.